# Can function argument have hint in cfscript (CF9)?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Can function argument have hint in cfscript (CF9)?

CFML style:

```
<cffunction name="myFunc" output="false" returntype="void">
  <cfargument name="arg1" type="arg1" default="default" hint="my hint">
  ...
</cffunction>
```

CF9 cfscript style:

```
public void function myFunc(string arg1='default') {
  ...
}
```

Where to specify hint of the argument (arg1) above?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The easiest way is to to use JavaDoc notation.

```
component{

/**
* @hint This is a hint
* @arg1 This is an argument hint
* @arg2 This is another argument hint 
*/
public void function myFunc(string arg1='default', numeric arg2) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

}

Comment: This method only attaches the hint to the function, but not to the argument 'arg1'.

Comment: I have altered it to show the right syntax.  Sorry about that.

Comment: oh I see! Thank you!  I can't find this from the documentation.

Answer (score -2):

I've not played with cf9, but you can do something like this in CF8:

```
<cffunction name="myFunc" output="false" returntype="void">
  <cfargument name="arg1" type="arg1" default="default" hint="my hint">
  <cfscript>
    //do stuff
  </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

Not ideal, but maybe an acceptable comprimise.

Comment: not sure how this is an answer... he asked how to write the equivalent of some code in cfscript, and you pasted back the same code that he provided.

Comment: Ben provided an alternative approach... The solution missed the key requirement, so it was probably better left as a comment, but definitely not worth a negative rating.